# Fetching data from DB2 Views

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, db2

Is fetching data from a DB2 view and DB2 table both are different or same please explain?
What are the things will change in connection string?

Comment: A view looks just like a table.  Nothing needs to change in the connection string or query.

Answer (score 2):

From the client perspective (CLP or Application) there's absolutely nothing different to fetch data from a VIEW or a TABLE. Although, depending on the complexity of the SQL SELECT of the view, it could be (but not necessarily) more slow.

There's nothing to change in the connection string. To fetch data you do SQL SELECT directly or create cursors the same way, should it be a VIEW or a TABLE.